# Insert blanks as NULL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm building an AWS pipeline to insert CSV files from S3 to an RDS MySQL DB. The problem I'm facing is that when it attempts to load the file, it treats blanks as empty strings instead of NULLs. For example, Line 1 of the CSV is:

```
"3","John","Doe",""
```

Where the value is an integer in the MySQL table, and of course the error in the pipeline is:

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'col4' at row 1
```

I was researching the jdbc MySQL paramaters to modify the connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://my-rds-endpoint:3306/my_db_name?    
jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
```

`jdbcCompliantTruncationis` is just an example, is there any of these parameters that can help me insert those blanks as nulls?

Thanks!

EDIT:
A little context, the CSV files are UNLOADS from redshift, so the blanks are originally NULLs when I put them in S3.

Comment: Can you convert them beforehand?

Comment: IF(urValue = '',null,urValue)

Comment: @AndyHolmes, good question, check the edit

Comment: @MXD, I thought about that, however the way you add the insert string to pipelines is like this: insert into table values (?,?,?,?) so if I apply that, i will get an error that there are not enough parameters.

Comment: if(urValue = '', urnewvalue = null, (at)urnewvalue = urvalue)  table values((at)urvalue)

Comment: You need to be able to compose your own custom `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement. If the tool doesn't allow it, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

> the csv files are UNLOADS from redshift

Then look at [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) for the Redshift UNLOAD command and add the `NULL AS` option. For example:

`NULL AS 'NULL'`

Comment: Hi! I tried this and the problem is that in the CSV I'll have NULL but the pipeline interprets it as 'NULL' when doing the insert so I keep receiving the same error

Comment: Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'col4' at row 1

Comment: Right, that was just an example. You need to figure out what the pipeline considers null, and use that in the unload command. It might be some version of the Null character: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Answer (score 1):

> use null as '\N' converts blank to null

```
unload ('SELECT * FROM table')
to 's3://path' credentials 
'aws_access_key_id=sdfsdhgfdsjfhgdsjfhgdsjfh;aws_secret_access_key=dsjfhsdjkfhsdjfksdhjkfsdhfjkdshfs'
delimiter '|' null as '\\N' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue using the **NULLIF** function:

```
insert into table values (NULLIF(?,''),NULLIF(?,''),NULLIF(?,''),NULLIF(?,''))
```

Comment: Please note it's a load from CSV files, accomplished by a third-party service.